# Android how to resize a layout after its image was resized

Tags: android

I have a layout with 3 images side-by-side. I use layout_weight to set them up :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#888888"
    tools:context="test_layout_resize.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hotdog"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hotdog"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout3"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/image3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/hotdog"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

For some reason, layout1, 2 and 3's height is that of the original hotdog image, not the shrunken one :

[3 hotdogs not at the top of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGMNi.png)

I tried getParent().requestLayout() or invalidate() in ImageView.onDraw(), neither of which changed anything.

How do I make the RelativeLayout's height resize to the new ImageView height ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use      `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` inside your all ImageView will solve your problem.

Hope it will help you :)